# How to concatenate if the adjacent cell value is true?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate text if the adjacent cell value is "True".

I have written code that works for all the text in the cells but I can't piece together code using an if statement.

The table begins on B6 and looks like this:

```
True   Butter
False  Cream
False  Milk
False  Water
True   Soda
```

I tried declaring an integer to use as a row and set it to add 1 if the condition is met.

Here is the code that strings together all of the cell values:

```
Sub JoinText()

Dim result As String
Dim comma As String
Dim col As String

comma = ","

For i = 6 To 10
    col = Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 3).Value
result = result & comma & col

Next

result = Right(result, Len(result) - Len(comma))

MsgBox (result)

End Sub
```

How the results display:

```
Butter,Cream,Milk,Water,Soda
```

Here is my modified code:

```
Dim result As String
Dim comma As String
Dim col As String
Dim row As Integer

row = 2
comma = ","

For i = 6 To 10

If col = Sheets("Test").Cells(i, row).Value = "True" Then
    col = Sheets("Test").Cells(i, row + 1).Value
End If

result = result & comma & col

Next

result = Right(result, Len(result) - Len(comma))

MsgBox (result)
```

What the result looks like now:

```
,,,,
```

I messed with the code and have been getting various results like:

```
Butter, Butter, Butter, Butter, Butter
```

or

```
,,,,Soda
```

Edit: I removed "col =" in the if statement and now my results are showing as “butter, butter, butter, soda, soda, soda”. How do I narrow it down to just two results?

Comment: For this example, I want it to display "Butter, Soda"

Comment: `If col = Sheets("Test").Cells(i, row).Value = "True" Then` remove that `col = `

Comment: Seem my answer below. Have you moved the `result = ...` into the if statement?

Comment: sorry i did forget to do that part ad now when I moved it in the if statement, it only displays the very last result no matter what value the adjacent cell is.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Tim Williams said, move `result = ...` into the if statement.

Example:

```vb
If Sheets("Test").Cells(i, row).Value = "True" Then
    col = Sheets("Test").Cells(i, row + 1).Value
    result = result & comma & col
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option explicit
public function concatConditional(r As Range, Optional delim As String = ",") As String
   Dim rowCnt    As Integer
   Dim v()       As Variant
   v = r.Value2
   concatConditional = ""
   for rowCnt = 1 to r.Rows.Count
      if v(rowCnt,1) then
         concatConditional = concatConditional & delim & v(rowCnt,2)
      end if
   next rowCnt
end function
```

I omitted error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this when I get home from work and let you know if this worked.